# Multidimensional list

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm am creating a **multidimensional list** where **rows** and **columns** are taken into consideration. The code would require the user to enter **n** number of times of digits depending on the **count**.

Example: The user is required to **enter numbers 5 times** and then the number is displayed as a **list of list**.

```
UserInput: 1 2 3
           4 5 6
           5.5 1 2
Output: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5.5,1,2]]
```

I'm able to do one dimensional list but when it comes to multidimensional list I'm lost in it. Here's my code i worked out so far:

```
rows = 5
table = rows*[0]
rowNumber = 0

while rowNumber < rows:
    userInput = input("Enter a number:").split()

    for i in range(len(userInput)):
         for j in range(len(userInput[i]):
                 table[i][j] = userInput

rowNumber +=1
print(table)
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Smells like homework :)

You need to create a list of lists. Right now your table is just a single dimensional list which has 0s. You'd want to create a list in the outer loop, and add to that in the inner ones. And when inner loop finishes, add that newly created list to the main list.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that userInput = input("Enter a number:").split() returns you a list. You can just use this list in the table directly, without having to parse it!

A 'row' of the table will then have userInput as its value. Also keep in mind the incorrect tabulation you have for nowNumber += 1

```
while rowNumber < rows:
    userInput = input("Enter a number:").split()

    table[rowNumber] = userInput

    rowNumber +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely straightforward to get strings of 5.5, 1, 2 to turn into a float, int, and int, but this gets it done:

```
rows = 5
table = []

print('Enter a number:')
while len(table) < rows:
    userInput = input().split()
    table.append([int(x) if int(float(x))==float(x) else float(x) for x in userInput ] )

print(table)
```

If I was reading too much into the details and something like this is ok:

```
[[1.1, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]
```

then this code is a little simpler:

```
rows = 5
table = []

print('Enter a number:')
while len(table) < rows:
    userInput = input().split()
    table.append( list( map( float, userInput ) ) )

print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this does feel like an assignment question I'll keep this discussion higher-level.

A multidimensional list is a list of lists (of lists..., as deep as required). Traditionally this would be created through a nested loop structure.

With list comprehensions it's pretty easy to create a two-dimensional list, although higher-order multidimensional lists can begin to look pretty ridiculous and can become difficult to read (`[ [ [ [ x ] for x in source_0 ] for y in source_1 ] for z in source_3 ]` to create a four-dimensional list).

It should be noted the constructs for making a fixed-depth multidimensional list are more obvious than a variable-depth multidimensional list.

Suppose you had to input the number of dimensions of the multidimensional list. There are a couple different ways to solve this problem, but my favorite uses a loop and a stack; the loop watches the length of the stack and keeping adding an additional list to the top item in the stack, then pushing the new list onto the stack. For example:

```
    def create_multidimensional_list( depth ):
        result = []
        stack = [ result ]
        while len( stack ) < depth:
           new_list = []
           stack[ -1 ].append( new_list )
           stack.append( new_list )
        return result
```

There's another aspect of multidimensional lists to mention: if they are rectangular or jagged. In a rectangular multidimensional list all of the siblings of a list item have the same depth, whereas a jagged multidimensional list (sometimes also referred to as a sparse multidimensional list) can have list items whose siblings have different depths; the above code for creating a multidimensional list creates a rectangular multidimensional list. Code for handling a rectangular multidimensional list is easier to write (especially if you know the depth beforehand), but jagged multidimensional lists can use less memory since you do not necessarily populate the list to its rectangular capacity.